# A basic C-ECHO SCP sample code which would work with FO-DICOM v.5

Tags: fo-dicom

I need **a very basic code snippet** implementing **C-ECHO SCP with FO-DICOM 5**. All examples I was able to find so far do not work, since, as far as I understand, the signatures of the major routines changed from v4 to v5 and the latter is as good as not documented (at least, no comprehensible howto examples).

Comment: I, for my part, am looking for an example of a DICOM server using FO-DICOM v4. If it existed on the FO-DICOM site, it seems to have vanished from there.